# unable to open div box as layer using z-index

Tags: html, css

I am trying to open action div box as layer in but unable to do that.

[image]

when i click on action button div box will open within that  only. it should be open as layer.
[image]

**Code:**

```css
ul {
  z-index: 2
}

table {
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr.No</th>
      <th>LeadCreated DateTime</th>
      <th>RetailerName</th>
      <th>ShopName</th>
      <th>Mobile</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Pincode</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="odd gradeX">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10-10-2017</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>9904773479</td>
      <td>Surat</td>
      <td>Surat</td>
      <td>304230</td>
      <td style="background: <?php if ($row->Status == 'InProcess') echo 'green';if ($row->Status == 'Closed') echo 'orange';if ($row->Status == 'Dead') echo 'black'; ?>;color: #FFFFFF">
        <?= $row->Status ?>
      </td>
      <td class="pbutton">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                                                                Action <span class="caret"></span>
                                                            </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right " role="menu" style="position: relative;width: 160px;z-index: 99">
            <li><a href="#viewleadmodal" data-id="<?= $row->LeadId ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewleadmodal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></span>&nbsp;View</a></li>
            <li><a href="followup.php?LeadId=1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Add Lead Update</a></li>
            <li><a href="leadedit.php"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="check_perform_sdelete('14');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `.btn-group` positioned relative and the `ul` positioned absolute. You may want to change the absolute positioning according to your liking.

The z-index can be removed.

```css
.btn-group {
  position: relative;
}

ul.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -160px;
  width: 160px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr.No</th>
      <th>LeadCreated DateTime</th>
      <th>RetailerName</th>
      <th>ShopName</th>
      <th>Mobile</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Pincode</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="odd gradeX">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10-10-2017</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>9904773479</td>
      <td>Surat</td>
      <td>Surat</td>
      <td>304230</td>
      <td style="background: <?php if ($row->Status == 'InProcess') echo 'green';if ($row->Status == 'Closed') echo 'orange';if ($row->Status == 'Dead') echo 'black'; ?>;color: #FFFFFF">
        <?= $row->Status ?>
      </td>
      <td class="pbutton">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                                                                Action <span class="caret"></span>
                                                            </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right " role="menu">
            <li><a href="#viewleadmodal" data-id="<?= $row->LeadId ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewleadmodal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></span>&nbsp;View</a></li>
            <li><a href="followup.php?LeadId=1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Add Lead Update</a></li>
            <li><a href="leadedit.php"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="check_perform_sdelete('14');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
ul.dropdown-menu{
  position:absolute !important;
}
```

or use inline styles

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right " role="menu" style="position: absolute;width: 160px;z-index: 99">
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the `ul.dropdown-menu` styles to make it absolute, either use `!important` or override the inline styles.

```
ul.dropdown-menu{
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 200px;
  top: 15%;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```css
ul.dropdown-menu {
  z-index: 2
}

table {
  z-index: 1
  position: relative;
}
ul.dropdown-menu{
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 200px;
  top: 15%;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr.No</th>
      <th>LeadCreated DateTime</th>
      <th>RetailerName</th>
      <th>ShopName</th>
      <th>Mobile</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Pincode</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="odd gradeX">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>10-10-2017</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>Test</td>
      <td>9904773479</td>
      <td>Surat</td>
      <td>Surat</td>
      <td>304230</td>
      <td style="background: <?php if ($row->Status == 'InProcess') echo 'green';if ($row->Status == 'Closed') echo 'orange';if ($row->Status == 'Dead') echo 'black'; ?>;color: #FFFFFF">
        <?= $row->Status ?>
      </td>
      <td class="pbutton">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                                                                Action <span class="caret"></span>
                                                            </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right " role="menu" style="position: relative;width: 160px;z-index: 99">
            <li><a href="#viewleadmodal" data-id="<?= $row->LeadId ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewleadmodal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></span>&nbsp;View</a></li>
            <li><a href="followup.php?LeadId=1"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Add Lead Update</a></li>
            <li><a href="leadedit.php"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="check_perform_sdelete('14');"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```